# Nginx not redirecting subdomain (instead directing to default)

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I have an *empty file* in sites-available

```
ubuntu@ip-111-11-11-111:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ ls
default dev.example.io
```

It is symlinked into sites-enabled:

```
ubuntu@ip-111-11-11-111:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Nov 14 17:59 dev.example.io -> ../sites-available/dev.example.io
```

I have a .conf file which specifies that this subdomain should use a different root:

```
http {
    server {
        root /var/www/html/dev/my-site/public_html/;
        server_name dev.example.io;

        location / {
        }
    }

    server {
        root /var/www/html/my-site/public_html/;

        location / {
        }
    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I have setup my DNS correctly, and reloaded the conf file.

The issue is that every time I go to `dev.example.io`, it redirects to the default site.  It seems like my setup is pretty barebones, and from all of the other similar questions I've found online (there's a lot) this seems like it should work.  But most of the questions I've seen also have their full (and seemingly mostly irrelevant) conf posted, which makes it hard to tell what *exactly* is the part that matters to the question.

**Are there any glaring errors here?**  Why doesn't dev.example.io serve from the dev public_html?

P.S. Is `location / {}` relevant to the question?  If not, I'll remove it.

Comment: The more I look into it, the more it seems the location lines, and everything having to do with sites-enabled|available is totally unnecessary.

Comment: answered @ stackoverflow